# Why does seaborn.axes_style get reset on Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter, seaborn

When I `seaborn.set()` for the first time in a Jupyter notebook, `seaborn.axes_style()['figure.facecolor']` is set to "white" as expected, but the value gets reset in the next cell. Why?

Python 3.7.3, IPython 7.5.0, seaborn 0.9.0

When I run the following code in a new Jupyter notebook, I get these outputs, which don't make sense to me:

Cell 1:

```py
import seaborn
seaborn.set()
print(seaborn.axes_style()['figure.facecolor'])
print(seaborn.axes_style()['figure.facecolor'])
```

Out 1:

```
    white
    white
```

Cell 2:

```py
print(seaborn.axes_style()['figure.facecolor'])
```

Out 2:

```
    (1, 1, 1, 0)
```

Cell 3:

```py
seaborn.set()
print(seaborn.axes_style()['figure.facecolor'])
```

Out 3:

```
    white
```

Cell 4:

```py
print(seaborn.axes_style()['figure.facecolor'])
```

Out 4:

```
    white
```

What am I missing?

The actual `matplotlib` plots are affected by this, and I need to get rid of it.

Also, since I'd like to perform `set()` every time, I tried putting it in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/00.py`, but it didn't work.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: It's a known IPython bug. Will share some links here later on.

Comment: Here is the open issue https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11098

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks a lot!
Btw I'm new to stackoverflow, how can I reward you for this? Because your answer seems like just a comment and apparently I can't upvote or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answer:

As ImportanceOfBeingErnest noted, it's caused by an IPython bug.

The following workaround did the trick for me, though it's not really desirable:

```
- Call set() in Cell 2 or below.
```